# Intellij Perl5 add Perl5 interpreter

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to use the intellij Perl Plugin, but I cannot configure the Perl5 SDK. When I open the `.pm` files I get the hint "Perl5 SDK is not configured". I can click on configure and it takes me to preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Perl5. Here I get the following:
[image]

At Perl5 Interpreter it says Disable Perl5 support. It's the only option in the dropdown. When I click on the gear I can choose "local" and then I can choose between "Add perlbrew Perl", "Add plenv Perl" and "Add system Perl". All options get me to the file system, but no matter which file I'm choosing nothing seems to be correct.

`perl -V` gives me the following:

```
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/Users/ephan/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/ephan/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/Users/ephan/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/ephan/perl5"
  @INC:
    /Users/ephan/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/ephan/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.2
    /Users/ephan/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/ephan/perl5/lib/perl5
    /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.30
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.30
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.2
    /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.30
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30
```

which option and which directory can I choose to make it work?

Comment: What is the output of `which perl` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this now on macOS 11.2.3. First I installed the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac).
Then I opened the IDE and installed the [perl plugin](https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/wiki/Getting-started) by choosing `Intellij IDEA->Preferences->Plugins` and searching for `perl`.

Then, chose `File->New->Project..` and then `Perl5` from the list:

[image]

then clicked the `Next` button, and clicked the cog wheel and chose `Add system Perl`, then chose the file `perl` in directory `/usr/bin` :

[image]

which gave me this new view

[image]

then clicked `Next` and chose a name for the new project :

[image]

and finally clicked the `Finish` button.

[image]

Now I added a new perl script to the project by clicking `File->New->Perl5 File`

[image]

and selected the name and type of file from the dialog :

[image]

then typed in a simple "Hello world" script in the editor :

[image]

Then chose `Run->Run..` from the menu :

[image]

and selected the `test.pl` run configuration from the dialog :

[image]

and that's it. It ran the script and gave the following output:

[image]

Comment: it worked, thank you! Intellij still can't find any sub definitions though. The error is `Unable to find sub definition, declaration, constant definition or typeglob aliasing`

Comment: I have this issue as well. Any suggestions?